# Yii2 Sorting on relation ( multivalued column)

Tags: sorting, yii2

I have two tables 1. Name :- id, name, label (text type). 2. Labels :- id, name .
In yii2, I have grid view for name mdoule. I want to add search and sort filter for label field.

ex:

table Name : 1, "tom", "1,2,3"

table Label : 1, "label A"
            2, "label B",
            3, "label C",

Answer (score 0):

In your search models search method insert this

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['label'] = [
    // The tables are the ones our relation are configured to
    'asc'  => ['label.name' => SORT_ASC],
    'desc' => ['label.name' => SORT_DESC],
];
```

And add this column to your grid view

```
[
    'filter'    => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\Label::find()->select(['id', 'name'])->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
    'attribute' => 'label_id',
    'value'     => 'label.name',
    'label'     => Yii::t('backend', 'Label'),
],
```

Ps.: you can read more about this [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/)

Comment: Thnks but In my problem, I have a field called 'Label' (type = text' ). In this field ids (more than one ) of labels stored. In label tab only id and name filed are there.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you want to sort the name by the number of labels or you want to display a column with all the labels belonging to a  name?